# Can CIL/IL change in different environments?

Tags: c#, reflection, cil, il

Given a utility method that searches for a Field that is backing a property that you do not have Set access to. 
Are there any environmental conditions that would cause this to fail once I have it working on my machine? 
Is the IL returned from GetILAsByteArray always going to be the same for a given assembly regardless of the conditions that you are running the application in?

```
    public static class HackUtil
    {
        public static FieldInfo GetFieldBackingProperty(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop)
        {
            var acc = prop.GetAccessors().Where(x => x.ReturnType != typeof(void)).First();
            var mb = acc.GetMethodBody();
            var ilb = mb.GetILAsByteArray();
            var ldField = ilb.Skip(ilb.Length - 6).ToArray();

            // try to match a getter like: get { return myVar; }
            if (ldField[0] == 0x7b /*ldfield opcode*/ && ldField[ldField.Length - 1] == 0x2a /*ret opcode*/)
            {
                var fields = prop.DeclaringType.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
                    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
                    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static
                    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
                    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

                // so the 4 bytes between those two opcodes should be our metadatatoken
                var matchingField = (from f in fields
                                     where f.MetadataToken == BitConverter.ToUInt32(ldField, 1)
                                     select f).FirstOrDefault();

                return matchingField;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

If so, any idea on what could be done to compensate for this?

Comment: IL is produced by the C# compiler on your dev machine.  It does not change when you run the program in a different environment.  Bypassing the setter is not a great idea, you can call it with reflection even if it is private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is the IL returned from `GetILAsByteArray` always going to be the same for a given assembly regardless of the conditions that you are running the application in?*

**Yes**, if the assembly is still the same.

Once an assembly (and therefore the IL in it) has been generated by the compiler, its contents will not change through normal use. Normal use includes things like having the .NET Framework load an assembly into memory, having it JIT-compile the IL code to assembly code, and executing methods.

Remember that IL is just intermediate language. Think of it as a blueprint for generating assembly code. Because of that, the runtimes have no need to change the IL: If they want to change a method's implementation (e.g. for optimization reasons), it's the assembly code they will adjust, not the IL.

That being said, I can see a few possibilities how the IL in an assembly might be changed; none of them are related to simply running a program in a different environment, though.

- If an assembly is **not strongly-named** (i.e. hashed and signed with a security certificate), someone could **tamper with** / modify it on-disk, e.g. using libraries such as Mono Cecil or Microsoft's Common Compiler Infrastructure (CCI).

  If you want the guarantee that an assembly cannot be modified after its generation without you noticing, make sure its strongly-named.
- The **unmanaged Profiling API** of the Common Language Runtime (CLR) offers the capability to replace methods with a new implementation.

  See for example the [MSDN Magazine article "Rewrite MSIL Code on the Fly with the .NET Framework Profiling API (.NET Internals)" by Aleksandr Mikunov](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188743.aspx).
- When you debug an assembly in Visual Studio and make changes to it while it is running (i.e. the **Edit-and-Continue** feature), I don't know if these changes could possibly be seen through reflection.

Comment: Thanks! I like how you covered the edge cases as well.